# converting pdf to html page wise using python

Tags: python, html, pdf, subprocess

I have this

```
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('FilePath'):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, 'page-*.pdf'):
    # matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
    subprocess.call('pdf2txt.py  > myoutput.html', shell = True)
```

I need to write subprocess for everytime a file is found of particular pattern[Filtered condition] do subprocess of pdf to html of that file.

How Can i dynamically change input given to subprocess.

Edits are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `glob` with `os` module to capture both the *.pdf* pattern and full absolute paths of input .pdf and output .html files:

```
import os
import glob

# CURRENT DIRECTORY OF SCRIPT  
cd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

for pdf in glob.glob(cd+'/*.pdf'):
    file = pdf.replace('.pdf', '')
    subprocess.call('python path/to/pdf2txt.py -o {0}.html -t html {1}'.format(file, pdf), 
                    shell = True)
```